# Calling all kind of web services with same code with C#?

Tags: c#, web-services

I want to ask about one situation. We think about written same web service with different technology. For example web api web service,.asmx web service,wcf web service, java xml web service... etc.
Normally if i want to call this web services i should write different code. 
Is it possible to call this kind of tech services with same code? How can i do ? 
Below code is a dummy code to call different type of tech's services.

```
    //calling web api web service

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync>Product>();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
    }

    //calling asmx web service

    localhost.WebService client = new localhost.WebService();
    client.Products(1);
```

Edit: All web service have same method and property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have soap services with exactly same wsdl, but created with different technology, you can call them with one peace of code. Moreover you can use any technology to create client, that can work with soap services. If this services is not soap service, you already can use single peace of code to work with them if they all is waiting for the same xml data. In this case you can use `HttpClient` class to send request to them. Moreover `HttpClient` is more general way to call any http endpoint independently of its internal technology, but it demand more work to get it works then other.

Comment: Could you give me samo code example to call with HttpClient? I only know  to call with httpclient in Web api.Could you do an example to call asmx or wcf service ?  Thanks for answer.

Comment: For example I found an example for asmx web services,https://quirkd.wordpress.com/2015/01/24/shorts-consuming-a-wcf-asmx-web-service-in-winrt/